# Running docker containers on a Kubernetes master node (outside of Kubernetes)

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I did some reading but couldn't find any definitive recommendation.

Here is the question: Running a Kubernetes cluster, what are the implications of running docker containers on the master node outside the scope of running them as Kubernetes pods but rather just directly run docker images with `docker run` that co-exist with the containers that make up Kubernetes on the master node?

Major concerns?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the point of using kubernetes and then running containers without k8s supervision? What is your use case?

Comment: Two different stakeholders, one being a service provider, the other being a service user. The service provider needs to run a minimal, heartbeat like service that is easily containerized but cannot put it into the cluster as the cluster is used by the service user.